# Primitive element for $F=\Bbb Q(i,\sqrt{11},\sqrt{3})$ over $\Bbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

The element $k$ is called a primitive element of $K$ over $F$.

Find $k$ $\in$ $F$ such that $F=\mathbb{Q}(k)$.

$F=\mathbb{Q}(I,\sqrt{11},\sqrt{3})$

Will $k=8$?

Comment: What is I here?  Do you mean $i$ (i.e., $\sqrt{-1}$)?

Comment: yes , thank you

Comment: What do you know about the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{11},\sqrt{3})$?

Comment: Take a look at [the proof](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~kbrown/6310/primitive.pdf) of the primitive element theorem

Comment: In the right margin of this page, in the list of **Related** questions, you will find several analogous questions about locating  primitive elements of extension fields of rationals gotten by adjoining several square roots. Please study those! Also, I'm sad to say, the list of questions you have asked is becoming more and more like a set of homework problems, copied verbatim. If you have difficulties with some basic concept here, please formulate a question about those instead. For example, I'm sure you were given examples of primitive elements in class. Are those crystal clear to you?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Look at $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{11})$

Comment: Thank you for your hint but I am not sure how can I use it ?

Comment: @qwertyui, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem#Constructive_results.

Comment: thank you but I am still confuse .

Comment: @tattwamasi amrutam  after I did the work ,I found k=8 , is it correct ?thanks

Comment: No. It is not because $\mathbb{Q}(8)$ is $\mathbb{Q}$ itself