# Find the Primitive Element k.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

The element $k$ is called a primitive element of $K$ over $F$.

Find $k \in F$ such that $F=\mathbb{Q}(k)$.

The problem I need to solve is $F=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{5}+i)$.

I know in a similar problem you had to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3}+i)$.

The multiple $i$'s are confusing me.

Am I supposed to show that $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{5}+i)=\mathbb{Q}(i+\sqrt{5}+i)?$

Comment: If you could prove that $\sqrt 5 +2i$ generated the field, that would certainly finish the job.  But I'm not sure the $2$ is really necessary...what is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 5 +i$?

Comment: Also, see the comments [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2225605/primitive-element-for-f-bbb-qi-sqrt11-sqrt3-over-bbb-q).

Answer (score 2):

In fact this field is just $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 5+i]$.  To see this, let $\alpha = \sqrt 5 +i$.  Then $$\alpha^2=4+2i\sqrt 5\implies \alpha^2-4 = 2i\sqrt 5$$

But then $$(\alpha^2-4)\times \alpha = 2i\sqrt 5 \left(\sqrt 5 +i\right)=10i-2\sqrt 5 $$

It follows that $$(\alpha^2-4)\times \alpha  +2\alpha = 12i$$ so we see that $$i\in \mathbb Q[\alpha]$$  and that is enough to complete the argument.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, all I need to show is that Q(i,sqrt(5)+i) = Q(sqrt(5)+i).  Sorry, I don't know how to do the LaTex in a comment.

Comment: Well, you need to find some $\alpha$ in your field which works.  I proposed $\alpha = \sqrt 5 +i$ because I suspected that was the simplest.  Your expression, $\sqrt 5 +2i$ probably works too.  Try it...see if you can get $i$ in that field (clearly that would suffice).

Comment: By the way, LaTex works the same way in comments as it does elsewhere.  If the expression is complicated, I often type my comment in the answer field so I can see if it compiles properly before cutting and pasting it to the comment field.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the conjugate is a good idea many times:

$$(\sqrt5+i)(\sqrt5-i)=6\implies \sqrt5-i=\frac6{\sqrt5+1}\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt5+i)\implies$$

$$\sqrt5+i-(\sqrt5-i)=2i\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt5+i)\implies i\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt5+i)$$

and we're done.